# is it possible to write a nonlinear piecewise function inside the objective function in Pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

I want to use Pyomo to solve a nonlinear optimization using Ipopt. In this regard I devised a function as an objective function in my code which itself uses another function inside it. the inner function is nonlinear and piecewise and is defined as follows.

```
def U3(x,omega,U_alpha3):
       if x<=omega/U_alpha3:
              return omega*x-U_alpha3/2*x**2
       else:
              return 0.5*omega**2/U_alpha3
```

But this function leads to this error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'IndexedComponent_slice' and 'numpy.float64'
```

considering that my decision variable goes inside x (which is 'IndexedComponent_slice' type) and omega and U_alpha3 are fixed parameters(which are 'numpy.float64' type)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Pyomo NL-file interface to Ipopt supports this via the [Expr_If](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/4f6f523483ffbf0eade463b1872885a140b607f1/pyomo/repn/tests/ampl/small12_testCase.py) expression class, given the standard caveats about the function you are defining being twice-continuously differentiable, etc. (which we do not verify for you).

Comment: thanks a lot but what about more than two conditions?! and is there any way to just compare instances of 'IndexedComponent_slice' and 'numpy.float64' data types for the sake of easiness?!

Comment: You can embed Expr_If clauses in other Expr_If clauses to make more complex expressions programmatically. This is accessing a very low-level feature of the AMPL solver library, which nonlinear solvers like Ipopt use for calculation of derivatives. It should only be used if you absolutely know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also, after some searching in the internet, realized that when I use value(x) instead of x, my error disappears! but I'm not sure whether this "value()" function usage is correct here. Can I use "value()" here?! (noting that x is my decision variable here)

Comment: No, using value() here is likely not what you want. You should not think of these constraint rules as callback functions that the solver will see. They are called once for each index to collect a static set of symbolic expressions that are then translated to an input that the solver understands. In the case of Ipopt, we write these expressions into what is called an NL file, which is a common input format used by solvers built on top of the AMPL solver library.