# Is it possible to define a nonlinear piecewise objective function in Pyomo with "Ipopt" solver?

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

In Pyomo with "Ipopt" solver, I am trying to define a nonlinear objective function to be piecewise such that when the decision variables q_i < 1, it is a quadratic function; otherwise it is a log function. As suggested by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437603/is-it-possible-to-write-a-nonlinear-piecewise-function-inside-the-objective-func), using the "Expr_If" expression should do the job. However, when I run the code (below), the solver indicates that it reaches an optimal solution and I can print the value of optimal decision variables by running:
`for x in model.q: print(model.q[x].value)`
but I can not print the optimal value of the objective function when I run:
`model.payoff()` such that I get this error "math domain error". This error might suggest that a log function is being evaluated at a negative value, but based on the objective function that I defined this should not happen. Also, I can calculate the value of the objective function by rewriting it (after obtaining the optimal solution) directly using the values of optimal solution by running the code:

```
payoff_ = 0
for i in model.P:
    if model.q[i].value>=1:
        payoff_ +=  model.Beta[i] * log(model.q[i])
    else:
        payoff_ += (-0.5)*model.Alpha[i] * (model.q[i]-1)**2
print(payoff_())
```

Do you know why I am getting the "math domain error" when I run `model.payoff()` ?

My code:

```
model = ConcreteModel()

#Define the set
model.P = Set(initialize=['P1','P2','P3','P4'])

#Parameters
model.Beta = Param(model.P, initialize = {'P1':1,'P2':1.2,'P3':1.4,'P4':1.6})
model.Alpha = Param(model.P, initialize = {'P1':0.1,'P2':0.2,'P3':0.3,'P4':0.4})

#Variables
model.q = Var(model.P)

#Objective
def Payoff(model):
    return sum(Expr_if(IF=model.q[i]>=1, THEN=model.Beta[i] * log(model.q[i]),
              ELSE=(-0.5)*model.Alpha[i] * (model.q[i]-1)**2) for i in model.P)
model.payoff = Objective(expr = Payoff, sense = maximize)

#Constraints
def limit(model, i):
    return -1.1<= model.q[i]
model.limit = Constraint(model.P, rule = limit)

def balance(model):
    return summation(model.q) == 0
model.balance = Constraint(rule = balance)

solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.solve(model)
#model.pprint()

model.payoff()  #  <-- This line produces an error
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd get more luck posting this in the Operations Research SE.

Comment: This should really be a comment instead of a proposed solution…